# Understanding the diagonal argument in the proof of a compactness theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, notation

In the proof of a compactness theorem (Rellich-Kondrachov) in Evans's *Partial Differential Equation*, the following argument is made:

> [image]
>   [image]

I'm not able to fully understand step 7.

Here are my **questions**:

- Would anyone elaborate how the diagonal argument is used to give the desired subsequence? (To be precise, assuming Step 6 is done, how to get Step 7?)
- How should one understand the notation $\limsup_{j,k\to\infty}$ appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

Let $F_1=(f_1(n))_n$ be a sub-sequence of $\mathbb N$ with $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{n\leq j<k} \|u_{f_1(j)}-u_{f_1(k)}\|<1.$

Take $G(1)=f_1(n_1)$ such that $\forall j>n_1\;(\|u_{f_1(n_1)}-u_{f_1(j)}\|<1).$

Let $F_2=(f_2(n))_n$ be a sub-sequence of $F_1$ with $f_2(1)=f_1(n_1),$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{n\leq j<k}\|u_{f_2(j)}-u_{f_2(k)}\|<1/2.$

Take $G(2)=f_2(n_2)$ with $n_2>1$ ( i.e. $G(2)>G(1)\;$) such that $\forall j>n_2\;(\|u_{f_2(n_2)}-u_{f_2(j)}\|<1/2).$

Let $F_3=(f_3(n))_n$ be  a sub-sequence of $F_2$ with $f_3(1)=f_2(n_2),$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{n\leq j<k}\|u_{f_3(j)}-u_{f_3(k)}\|<1/3.$ ET CETERA.

Consider the sequence $(u_{G(n)})_n.$

This is with the assumption that for any $\delta>0$ and any sub-sequence $F$ of $\mathbb N$ there is a sub-sequence $F'=(f'(n))_n$ of the sequence $F$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{n\leq j<k}\|u_{f'(j)}-u_{f'(k)}\|<\delta.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does the subscript $n$ in $(f_1(n))_n$ mean?

Comment: $(f_1(n))_n$ denotes the sequence $(f_1(1),f_1(2),f_1(3),....).$.. I prefer  that to  "the sequence $ f_1(n)$"  or   "the sequence $(f_1(n))$ " because it can be confusing if at some point you have to refer to a member $f_1(n)$ of the sequence or have to enclose an individual value $ f_1(n)$ in brackets..... In texts, different authors use different notations for sequences.